How to grep a next line json file
I have this multiple json file containing below and i want to capture png with enabled:true status.
"png": {
    "enabled": true,
    "status": false
  },
"jpeg": {
    "enabled": false,
    "status": false
  },

Tried this but it only displays enabled: true. i want to display the code block name PNG as well.
grep -Er '"enabled:"\s*true

Don't use grep to filter JSON, but use tools written to "understand" JSON and its syntax without being confused by white space, line breaks, or unordered keys; such as jq.
To get {"png":{"enabled":true,"status":false}}, run:
to_entries[] | select(.value.enabled) | from_entries

To only get "png" or png (raw output):
to_entries[] | select(.value.enabled).key

